# Why does it say "The field is required" in postman even if it's nullable?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, postman, repository-pattern

I have connected my asp.net core project to MS SQL server and am trying to test my APIs after writing the controllers. Here are 2 of the data models that I am trying to use.

```
 public partial class Content
    {
        public Guid CCuid { get; set; }
        public Guid CPuid { get; set; }
        public string? CContents { get; set; }
        public decimal? CAmount { get; set; }
        public string? CCheckNumber { get; set; }
        public int? CQuantity { get; set; }
        public string? CNotes { get; set; }
        public DateTime CDateProcessed { get; set; }
        public string? CUserName { get; set; }
        public virtual Vompackage? CPu { get; set; } 
    }


 public partial class Package
      {
        public Package()
        {
            Contents = new HashSet<Content>();
        }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Unique Package Identifier
        /// </summary>
        public Guid PPuid { get; set; }
        public Guid PSuid { get; set; }
        public string? PTrackingNumber { get; set; }
        public string? PBolnumber { get; set; }
        public string? PProductCode { get; set; }
        public int? PQuantity { get; set; }
        public int? PPallets { get; set; }
        public int? PBoxes { get; set; }
        public string? PNotes { get; set; }
        public DateTime PDateEntered { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Vomshipment? PSu { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

Now I am trying to add a content using postman. When I tried to add the following data,

```
{
    "cAmount": 2332,
    "cCheckNumber": "",
    "cQuantity": 133,
    "cNotes": "thank u ",
    "cDateProcessed": "2020-12-02T13:40:47.207",
    "cUserName": "ztinsley",
    "CPu": null
    }
```

It gives 400 response, and

```
"errors": {
    "CPu": [
        "The CPu field is required."
    ]
```

I used `null!` to make `CPu` nullable. And when I tested GET method to pull all the contents, it says `"cPu": null` for every data. Why is it having trouble adding a new data? I also tried to add `options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true` in `AddControllers()`, but the it gives me 500 response. Please help!

P.S.
I have attached my controller to see if I made any mistakes.

```
   [Produces("application/json")]
        [ApiController]
        [Route("api/content")]
        public class ContentController : Controller
        {
            private readonly IContentRepository _contentReporitory;
    
            public ContentController(IContentRepository contentReporitory)
            {
                _contentReporitory = contentReporitory;
            }
   [HttpGet("{ccuid}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Content>> GetContentById(Guid ccuid)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _contentReporitory.GetContentById(ccuid);

                if (result == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                    "Error retrieving data from the database");
            }
        } 
            [HttpPost("addcontent")]
            public async Task<ActionResult<Content>> AddContent([FromBody]Content content)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (content == null)
                        return BadRequest();
    
                    var newContent = await _contentReporitory.AddContent(content);
    
                    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetContentById),
                        new { id = newContent.CCuid }, newContent);
    
    
                } catch (Exception)
                {
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
                }
            }
    
        }
    }
```

My repository:

```
    public class ContentRepository : IContentRepository
    {
        private readonly OperationsContext _operationsContext;

        public ContentRepository(OperationsContext operationsContext)
        {
            _operationsContext = operationsContext;
        }

        public async Task<Content> AddContent(Content content)
        {
            var result  = await _operationsContext.Contents.AddAsync(content);
            await _operationsContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return result.Entity;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the on the API side, CPU field is marked as required and it's indicating the validation error in the response.

I would try sending CPU as an empty object `{}`, or try passing a dummy package content just to check if its indeed a validation error. 

Do you have the API code? If so can you share it?

Comment: It has nothing to do with json and postman. Your API  returns the validation error. You have to post  API code and ask the same question

Comment: Hi, I have added my controller that adds the content. Would would see if it helps ?

Comment: You have set: `Shipment PSu` to `null` , not `Cpu`!

Comment: Oops, I forgot to update it in the question. I did change it immediately after the first few comments!

Answer (score 2):

All project templates starting with .NET 6 (C# 10) enable the nullable context for the project. Projects created with earlier templates don't include this element, and these features are off unless you enable them in the project file or use pragmas. It means `CPu` is treated as a non-nullable property.

So you can simply send `{}` instead of `null`:

```
{
    "cAmount": 2332,
    "cCheckNumber": "",
    "cQuantity": 133,
    "cNotes": "thank u ",
    "cDateProcessed": "2020-12-02T13:40:47.207",
    "cUserName": "ztinsley",
    "CPu": {}
    }
```

Or just set

```
public virtual Package? CPu { get; set; }
```

Then you can send `"CPu": null`.

You can refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types#setting-the-nullable-context) to learn more.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did add ? after the return type and it returns 500 error now, whether I include "CPu": {} or not.

Comment: Do you get 500 error after you add `options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true` ? Just add `?` or send `{}` will not cause 500 error. May be you need to debug to check which line cause the error.